# how to calculate monthly average temperature in a time series for different years in matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, for-loop, temperature

I have a matrix including 2 columns .The first one indicates date from January first 2001 to December 31th 2020 and the second column shows the daily temperature.

I have a matrix including 2 columns. The first one indicates date from January first 2001 to December 31th 2020 and the second column shows the daily temperature. how to calculate average monthly temperature for 20 years. the result has 12*20 (rows and columns).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by converting your timestamps into MATLAB `datetime` instances, building a `timetable`, and then using [`retime`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timetable.retime.html), like this:

```matlab
% First column is days after 2001-01-01; second column is temperature
values = [(0:7304)', randi([0 20], 7305, 1)];

% Make a timetable
values_tt = timetable(datetime(2001,01,01) + days(values(:,1)), values(:,2));

% Retime to get monthly average
retime(values_tt, 'monthly', 'mean')
```

Comment: Dear Edric, I received an error in Matlab; Undefined function 'timetable' for input arguments of type 'datetime'

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? `timetable` was introduced in R2016b....

Comment: R2014b. yes it does not work for that. Is there another way without using timetable function?.

Comment: Hm, in R2014b, you're going to have to use a combination of perhaps `datevec` to figure out the unique month, and then `accumarray` to perform the mean-by-group operation. Unfortunately, `accumarray` is kind of tricky to use (which is why things like `retime` were invented).